# What partioning format?

Tags: windows

Hey everyone Im whiping out Ubuntu and going back to windows 7. Im currently formating my main partion of 120gb and im wondering what partion type it should be? thanks

I booted the windows installer and it said that it cannot be installed on that drive, I deleted those partions made one big one and will try again

Comment: While the exact error message was not provided it might also be a kind of odd partitioning and UEFI configuration issue. E.g. the Windows installer refuses to do a MBR install in certain situations where it detects another (completely unrelated) GPT partitioned hard drive. After removing the GPT paritioned drive, Windows can be installed without further interruption.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to partition in any specific format, the Windows 7 installation has a partition manager (very limited) that will format the partition you want in the type that it needs (NTFS).

Comment: It can even delete your current partition(s) and add new ones.

Answer (score 0):

How To Install Windows 7 - Ultimate X86-64 Over Ubuntu 10.10 - Desktop X86-64:

1. Press any key to boot the Windows 7 installation disc.

   [image: http://mytestingsite.djun.net/storage/askubuntu_com_install_windows_7_x86_64_over_ubuntu_10_10_desktop_x86_64_1.jpg]
2. Wait patiently.

   [image: http://mytestingsite.djun.net/storage/askubuntu_com_install_windows_7_x86_64_over_ubuntu_10_10_desktop_x86_64_2.jpg]
3. Wait patiently.

   [image: http://mytestingsite.djun.net/storage/askubuntu_com_install_windows_7_x86_64_over_ubuntu_10_10_desktop_x86_64_3.jpg]
4. Enter desired language settings and click "next".

   [image: http://mytestingsite.djun.net/storage/askubuntu_com_install_windows_7_x86_64_over_ubuntu_10_10_desktop_x86_64_4.jpg]
5. Click "install".

   [image: http://mytestingsite.djun.net/storage/askubuntu_com_install_windows_7_x86_64_over_ubuntu_10_10_desktop_x86_64_5.jpg]
6. Accept the license agreement and click "next".

   [image: http://mytestingsite.djun.net/storage/askubuntu_com_install_windows_7_x86_64_over_ubuntu_10_10_desktop_x86_64_6.jpg]
7. Click "custom".

   [image: http://mytestingsite.djun.net/storage/askubuntu_com_install_windows_7_x86_64_over_ubuntu_10_10_desktop_x86_64_7.jpg]
8. Click on your operating system partition (eg disk 0 partion 1) and click "drive options".

   [image: http://mytestingsite.djun.net/storage/askubuntu_com_install_windows_7_x86_64_over_ubuntu_10_10_desktop_x86_64_8.jpg]
9. Click "delete", which will delete your operating system partition.

   [image: http://mytestingsite.djun.net/storage/askubuntu_com_install_windows_7_x86_64_over_ubuntu_10_10_desktop_x86_64_9.jpg]
10. Click "ok".

    [image: http://mytestingsite.djun.net/storage/askubuntu_com_install_windows_7_x86_64_over_ubuntu_10_10_desktop_x86_64_10.jpg]
11. Click on your swap partition (eg disk 0 partition 1) and click "delete", which will delete your swap partition.

    [image: http://mytestingsite.djun.net/storage/askubuntu_com_install_windows_7_x86_64_over_ubuntu_10_10_desktop_x86_64_11.jpg]
12. Click "ok".

    [image: http://mytestingsite.djun.net/storage/askubuntu_com_install_windows_7_x86_64_over_ubuntu_10_10_desktop_x86_64_12.jpg]
13. Click on your hard drive (eg Disk 0) which should now have no partitions, and click "next", which will tell the Windows 7 installer to manually create optimal partitions for windows (if you would prefer you can manually create a single NTFS partition).

    [image: http://mytestingsite.djun.net/storage/askubuntu_com_install_windows_7_x86_64_over_ubuntu_10_10_desktop_x86_64_13.jpg]
14. Wait patiently.

    [image: http://mytestingsite.djun.net/storage/askubuntu_com_install_windows_7_x86_64_over_ubuntu_10_10_desktop_x86_64_14.jpg]
15. Wait patiently (or you can click "restart now").

    [image: http://mytestingsite.djun.net/storage/askubuntu_com_install_windows_7_x86_64_over_ubuntu_10_10_desktop_x86_64_15.jpg]

    15b. DO NOT PRESS ANY KEY! (You don't want to boot the DVD again at this time.)

    [image: http://mytestingsite.djun.net/storage/askubuntu_com_install_windows_7_x86_64_over_ubuntu_10_10_desktop_x86_64_15b.jpg]
16. Wait patiently.

    [image: http://mytestingsite.djun.net/storage/askubuntu_com_install_windows_7_x86_64_over_ubuntu_10_10_desktop_x86_64_16.jpg]
17. Wait patiently.

    [image: http://mytestingsite.djun.net/storage/askubuntu_com_install_windows_7_x86_64_over_ubuntu_10_10_desktop_x86_64_17.jpg]
18. Wait patiently.

    [image: http://mytestingsite.djun.net/storage/askubuntu_com_install_windows_7_x86_64_over_ubuntu_10_10_desktop_x86_64_18.jpg]
19. Wait patiently as the computer reboots.

    [image: http://mytestingsite.djun.net/storage/askubuntu_com_install_windows_7_x86_64_over_ubuntu_10_10_desktop_x86_64_19.jpg]
20. Wait patiently as Windows 7 boots and enters setup.

    [image: http://mytestingsite.djun.net/storage/askubuntu_com_install_windows_7_x86_64_over_ubuntu_10_10_desktop_x86_64_20.jpg]
21. Wait patiently as your hardware is analyzed.

    [image: http://mytestingsite.djun.net/storage/askubuntu_com_install_windows_7_x86_64_over_ubuntu_10_10_desktop_x86_64_21.jpg]
22. Enter a username, and host name, then click "next".

    [image: http://mytestingsite.djun.net/storage/askubuntu_com_install_windows_7_x86_64_over_ubuntu_10_10_desktop_x86_64_22.jpg]
23. Choose a password and click "next".

    [image: http://mytestingsite.djun.net/storage/askubuntu_com_install_windows_7_x86_64_over_ubuntu_10_10_desktop_x86_64_23.jpg]
24. If you have a product key enter it, if not you can install windows 7 as a 30 day trial. Click "next".

    [image: http://mytestingsite.djun.net/storage/askubuntu_com_install_windows_7_x86_64_over_ubuntu_10_10_desktop_x86_64_24.jpg]
25. Choose your Update settings. If you aren't sure what to pick go with "use recommended settings". Click "next".

    [image: http://mytestingsite.djun.net/storage/askubuntu_com_install_windows_7_x86_64_over_ubuntu_10_10_desktop_x86_64_25.jpg]
26. Setup time and date, then click "next".

    [image: http://mytestingsite.djun.net/storage/askubuntu_com_install_windows_7_x86_64_over_ubuntu_10_10_desktop_x86_64_26.jpg]
27. Choose desired network classification for your currently attached network connection. (Choose public if you are not sure if you are connected to a safe home or workplace network.)

    [image: http://mytestingsite.djun.net/storage/askubuntu_com_install_windows_7_x86_64_over_ubuntu_10_10_desktop_x86_64_27.jpg]
28. Wait patiently.

    [image: http://mytestingsite.djun.net/storage/askubuntu_com_install_windows_7_x86_64_over_ubuntu_10_10_desktop_x86_64_28.jpg]
29. Wait patiently.

    [image: http://mytestingsite.djun.net/storage/askubuntu_com_install_windows_7_x86_64_over_ubuntu_10_10_desktop_x86_64_29.jpg]
30. Wait patiently.

    [image: http://mytestingsite.djun.net/storage/askubuntu_com_install_windows_7_x86_64_over_ubuntu_10_10_desktop_x86_64_30.jpg]
31. You have successfully installed Windows 7, and are currently logged in under the user account you created during the setup procedure.

    [image: http://mytestingsite.djun.net/storage/askubuntu_com_install_windows_7_x86_64_over_ubuntu_10_10_desktop_x86_64_31.jpg]

Comment: Aside from fighting spammers, the rationale behind this rule is also that a good answer does not have to be a link- or screenshot-hell. Screenshots are useful to document the solution (or the state before and after) or tricky parts, but not where the system tells you to wait by showing a progress bar, spinner or something similar, or when on-screen instructions are sufficient to follow and providing clear choices. Overusing screenshots leads to the reader not remembering what s/he did, thinking of the whole procedure as very difficult while it is not and may be also belittled.

Comment: Some magazines and websites have taken this style to extremes to generate more clicks and page impressions on the web while also thinking of their readers as not very smart. However here at stackexchange/AskUbuntu, things are different. Short and structured ansers where you don't have to scroll down 3 or more screens are generally prefered.